# How to send a tweet with a hashtag in it?

Tags: php, twitter

So basically I'm trying to send tweets with Twitter API. I'm using OAuth API. Here is my code :

```
$tweet = "hey everyone !";
function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$request = $connection->post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=" . urlencode($tweet));
echo json_encode($request);
```

And it works... But... if I put a hashtag in my tweet, like for example

```
$tweet = "Here is a #second test";
```

Then it gets cut before the #. Why ? How to prevent that ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your $tweet.

Comment: Still does not work... I updated the code though.

Comment: Sorry, it actually works, just that I forgot to encode in my .NET code that communicates with my custom Twitter API... Thanks :)